# How do I stop spinner valueFactory from adding values twice in javafx

Tags: java, database, javafx, spinner

I created two table on a database(Product Records and Sales Records). I'm trying to increase and decrease the price value (by the default price value in a Product database) on the price textfiled so that the user can get the total price value when the spinner value(which is quantity value) is increasing or decreasing.

so when enter key is clicked on productID textfiled which has the productID inputed, it goes true the Product Records table and set productname,price,quantity to their textfileds and quantity value to the spinner textfiled. this is the code for the ActionEvent for on productID textfiled.
i have aready created a connection on the main class

```
private void ProCodeEnterKeyAction(){
    try {
        psta=s.connect.prepareStatement("select productname,price,AVAILABLEQTY from ProductRecords where productID=?");
        psta.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textfiledProCode.getText()));
        res=psta.executeQuery();

        if(res.next()){
            textfiledProName.setText(res.getString("productname"));
            textfiledPrice.setText(res.getInt("price")+"");

            tp=Integer.parseInt(textfiledPrice.getText());// to hold the default price value

            spinValue=new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1,res.getInt("AVAILABLEQTY"));
            spin.setValueFactory(spinValue);

            spin.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Integer> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) {
                    try {
                        if (newValue>oldValue) {
                            textfiledPrice.setText((Integer.parseInt(textfiledPrice.getText())+tp)+"");
                        }
                        else if(newValue<=res.getInt("AVAILABLEQTY")){
                            textfiledPrice.setText((Integer.parseInt(textfiledPrice.getText())-tp)+"");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            al=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            al.setTitle("Infomation");
            al.setContentText("Product Not Found");
            al.showAndWait();
            textfiledProCode.setText("");
            textfiledProName.setText("");
            textfiledPrice.setText("");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when the program comes up, productID textfiled is inputed and hit enter key, all the values are outputed when spinner is increased/decreased for the first time it works fine. But when i do the same thing with another productID and start increasing/decreasing the spinner it always add the price value by twice. like

1500+1500=3000 but am getting 1500+1500=4500.

when i print out oldValue and newValue the output will be twice the value

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to answer without a MVCE, but with the situation you describe and the code you show it looks like you forget to remove the previous listener. Either you should move the listener addition elsewhere (in a method `public/private void initialize()` with @FXML annotation for example), or you should remove the changeListener previously created before adding the new one (which is actually the same).

Comment: Thanks. I have seen my mistake, Your solution worked